# Not understanding the third solution to an Exponential Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$(2x)^{ x^2-12 }=(2x)^{ x }$$

I assumed that since the only difference here in the two expressions set equal to each other is the exponents, I will just set the exponents equal to each other and solve from there as such:

$$x^2-12=x\quad \Rightarrow x^2-x-12=0$$

$$(x+3)(x-4)=0\quad \Rightarrow \quad x=-3\quad or\quad x=4$$

However, the book lists the solutions as $x=4\quad or \quad x=0.5$

Why is this? Where did the $0.5$ come from?

Comment: the exponent in the left should be $x^2-12$, instead of $2x-12$

Comment: $1^3 = 1 = 1^4 \;$ but $\; 3\neq 4 \:\:$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $0.5$ came from the fact that $1$ to any power remains $1$, so we get $(2\cdot 0.5)^a=(2 \cdot 0.5)^b$ and we do not demand that $a=b$

Comment: Wow. I didn't even realize that. Is $-3$ still a solution? I double checked with wolfram alpha and it seems to be so, but my answer key excluded it.

Comment: It depends on whether you are willing to compute $(-6)^{-3}$.  Often we don't like raising negative numbers to powers that are not positive integers, but I believe negative integers should be allowed as well.  In that case $-3$ is a solution.